# IBM Cloud Private Catalog doesn't display Helm charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm, ibm-cloud-private

The catalog page in IBM Cloud Private is empty, and the following error message is in the helm-api pod logs:

```
'ERROR' 'getChartsFromRepo(recursive) error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN raw.githubusercontent.com:443’
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a bad IP Address for the DNS server in the `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces` files.

1. In the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, replace the `dns-nameservers` parameter value with 8.8.8.8, or your DNS server's IP address.  in
2. In the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, replace the name server value with 8.8.8.8, or your DNS server's IP address.
3. From the IBM Cloud Private UI, open the **Deployments** page, and delete the **dns-kube** pod.

Once that pod is recreated, you should be able to view Helm charts in the catalog.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem for IBM CAM 3.1.2 and IBM Cloud Private 3.1.2 installation (offline installation). Helm charts not appeared in the Catalog page.

I solved the problem by manually deleting the below Helm charts: (Go to IBM Cloud Private web console, Manage > Helm Repositories)

```
ibm-charts
ibm-community
ppc64le-isv-charts
ibm-charts-public
```

(You can delete them by clicking the icon ・・・ on the right side, then click delete)

After all of the above charts deleted, go to Manage > Helm Repositories > Sync repositories. Then, go to Catalog, and you will find some available charts (eg: ibm-cam, etc)