# IBM Cloud Private doesn't display Helm charts

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-private

Has anyone experienced the following issue with Helm repositories?

Catalog->Helm Charts is empty. 

There are two 'default' helm repositories - one "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable/" and second is 'local-charts' (https://192.168.1.100:8443/helm-repo/charts).

The only error I noticed is in helm-api pod logs (every time I refresh repos page or try to sync repos) is

2018-01-08T21:16:43.704Z 'ERROR' 'getChartsFromRepo(recursive) error:  connect ECONNREFUSED 119.28.7.181:443'

I already restarted helm-api and helmrepo pods as well as kube-dns pods.

Moreover, attempt to add google repo (https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/) fails with the same error:

2018-01-08T21:32:37.311Z 'FINE' 'inspect-client'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.327Z 'FINE' 'isValidPostPayloadentry'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.327Z 'FINE' 'repos/ POST entry'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.327Z 'FINE' 'isValidPostPayloadexit'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.327Z 'FINE' 'inspect-client -> redirecting to next'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.561Z 'ERROR' 'checkUrlForIndexYaml error:  connect ECONNREFUSED 119.28.7.181:443'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.561Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.561Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["suppMessages","invalidIndex"] en {"url":"https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"}'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.562Z 'FINE' 'err.statusCode:  400'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.562Z 'FINE' 'statusCode:  400'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.562Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.562Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode","400"] en '

2018-01-08T21:32:37.562Z 'FINE' 'configureAndSendError'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.562Z 'FINE' '{"statusCode":400,"message":"Invalid request : index.yaml at https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com is not valid"}'

2018-01-08T21:32:37.562Z 'FINE' 'getErrorResponse'

[0mPOST /helm-api/api/v1/repos [33m400 [0m251.259 ms - 124[0m

Comment: It might be a DNS problem. Will you try the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931208/ibm-cloud-private-catalog-doesnt-display-helm-charts?

Comment: Thank you for you help.
I fixed that issue yesterday by completely reinstalling ICP. There were two possible source of that problem: Tarball archive I put into cluster/images directory before deploying the cluster was corrupted. It is also possible that the issue was with networking - I had a bridge network configured on that VM (br0 on top of eth). I removed it before ICP re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting your solution so people are aware there's an answer:

"I fixed that issue yesterday by completely reinstalling ICP. There were two possible source of that problem: Tarball archive I put into cluster/images directory before deploying the cluster was corrupted. It is also possible that the issue was with networking - I had a bridge network configured on that VM (br0 on top of eth). I removed it before ICP re-install."  – Yerzhan Beisembayev

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Workaround (hattip @Dave Hay) is to

1. Make sure you have `kube-ctl` installed and configured on the master node: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/manage_cluster/cfc_cli.html
2. Install `helm-cli` on the master node: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/app_center/create_helm_cli.html
3. Add the repo: `helm repo add ibm-charts https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable/`

Now you can manually `search` and `install` using the helm CLI. The UI does not update.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem for IBM CAM 3.1.2 and IBM Cloud Private 3.1.2 installation (offline installation). Helm charts not appeared in the Catalog page.

I solved the problem by manually deleting the below Helm charts:
(Go to IBM Cloud Private web console, Manage > Helm Repositories)

- ibm-charts
- ibm-community
- ppc64le-isv-charts
- ibm-charts-public

(You can delete them by clicking the icon ・・・ on the right side, then click delete)

After all of the above charts deleted, 
go to Manage > Helm Repositories > Sync repositories. 
Then, go to Catalog, and you will find some available charts (eg: ibm-cam, etc)